# Java source code has many errors after the protoc compiled

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

My .proto file:

```
package com.xxxxx.cloud.module.proxy.protobuf;

option java_package = "com.xxxxx.cloud.module.proxy.protobuf";
option java_outer_classname = "ProxyHttpProtocol";

message Request{
    required string domain = 1;
    required string url = 2;
    required string body = 3;
    required int32 port = 4;
    required string method = 5;
}
```

some errors in java source code:

```
1、throw e.setUnfinishedMessage(this);//Could not find symbol
2、makeExtensionsImmutable(); //cloud not find symbol
3、ensureFieldAccessorsInitialized //cloud not find symbol
....more
```

I can't find any documentation to explain the reasons for these errors.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're missing the protobuf-java jar-file in your buildpath. You can either create it yourself by downloading the protobuf sources and running `mvn package` in the java directory of the download, or directly download the jar-file from the [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.protobuf%22%20a%3A%22protobuf-java%22).

Once you have the jar file, just add it to your project (either as maven dependency, or directly including it in your build path, depending on your setup).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, You said I was ready, I checked the source code for protobuf-java, there is really no found